# How to create update form in a for loop?

Tags: python, django

I listing my customers in a table with for loop. I want to change one attribute (`user`) with a form in this table. For doing that I have to take customer's information and update that. But I don't know how can take a customer's id in a loop.
this is my table:

[image]

> ValueError at /customers Cannot assign "'1'": "Customer.user" must be
> a "UserProfile" instance.

How can I take specific customer object and update it?

Here are my codes.

**views.py**

```
def customer_list(request):
    current_user = request.user
    userP = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=current_user)
    customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(company=userP[0].company.comp_name)

    # Assign
    form = AssignForm(request.POST or None)
        if request.POST:
         customer_id = request.POST.get('customer_id', None)
         customer = Customer.objects.get(id=customer_id)
         customer.user = request.POST.get('user', None)
         customer.save()
         return redirect('user:customer_list')

    myFilter = TableFilter(request.GET, queryset=customer_list.all())

    context = {
        'customer_list': customer_list,
        'myFilter': myFilter,
        'form': form

    }
    return render(request, 'customer_list.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class UserProfile(AbstractUser, UserMixin):
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, unique=False)
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4(), editable=False, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**customer_list.html**

```
<table id="multi-filter-select" class="display table table-striped table-hover grid_" >
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Customer Name</th>
                                            <th>Country</th>
                                            <th>E-Mail</th>
                                            <th>Phone</th>
                                            <th>VAT Number</th>
                                            <th>Operations</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Customer Name</th>
                                            <th>Country</th>
                                            <th>E-Mail</th>
                                            <th>Phone</th>
                                            <th>VAT Number</th>
                                            <th>Quick Operations</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                    <tbody>
                                    {% for customer in customer_list %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{customer.customer_name}}</td>
                                            <td>{{customer.country}}</td>
                                            <td>{{customer.email}}</td>
                                            <td>{{customer.telephone}}</td>
                                            <td>{{customer.VATnumber}}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <a href="/customers/{{ customer.id }}/profile" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="View Customer" ><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
                                                    <a href="/customers/{{ customer.id }}/update" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Update Info" ><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                                                    <a href="/pdfs/{{ customer.id }}/list" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-chart-line" data-toggle="tooltip" title="View Analyses" ></i></a>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo{{ forloop.counter }}">Assign</button>
                                                      <div id="demo{{ forloop.counter }}" class="collapse">
                                                        {% if customer.user == null %}
                                                            <form method="post">
                                                                {% csrf_token %}
                                                                {{ form|crispy }}
                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ">Assign</button>
                                                            </form>

                                                        {% else %}
                                                            Assigned to {{ customer.user.first_name }} {{ customer.user.last_name }}
                                                        {% endif %}
                                                      </div>


                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
</table>
```

**forms.py**

```
class AssignForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('user',)
```

**traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/customers

Django Version: 3.1.4
Python Version: 3.8.8
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'register',
 'customer',
 'financial_analysis',
 'ocr',
 'core',
 'approvals',
 'crispy_forms',
 'ckeditor',
 'rest_framework',
 'requests',
 'ckeditor_uploader',
 'django_filters',
 'activity_log']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'activity_log.middleware.ActivityLogMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\customer\views.py", line 57, in customer_list
    customer.user = request.POST.get('user', None)
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 215, in __set__
    raise ValueError(

Exception Type: ValueError at /customers
Exception Value: Cannot assign "'1'": "Customer.user" must be a "UserProfile" instance.
```

Comment: Also use `request.method == 'POST' `, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method

Comment: And I don't understand how the accepted answer could have helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add an additional field to your form to let your know the customer's id so that you can later take customer's information and update that.

customer_list.html

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="{{ customer.id }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ">Assign</button>
</form>
```

on views.py

```
def customer_list(request):
    ...
    if request.POST:
        customer_id = request.POST.get('customer_id',None)
        customer = Customer.objects.get(id=customer_id)
        user = UserProfile.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('user',None))
        customer.user = user
        customer.save()
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. But there is an error **ValueError at /customers
Cannot assign "'1'": "Customer.user" must be a "UserProfile" instance.** I will add traceback to my question